# Cut 3D Mesh in R

Tags: r, rgl

I've tried to create a 3D mesh looking like a cylinder and then cut it in half as following:

```
library(rgl)
library(Morpho)

xpos = c(-500,500)
ypos = c(0,0)
zpos = c(-200,-200)
rad = 50

cylinder = cylinder3d(center = cbind(xpos,ypos,zpos), radius = rad, sides = 100)
plot3d(cylinder, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab ="")
upperHalf = cutMeshPlane(cylinder,v1 = c(0,0,-200), normal = c(0,0,1),keep.upper = TRUE)
plot3d(t(upperHalf$vb), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab ="")
plot3d(upperHalf) #this produces an error: index out of bounds
```

The first plot shows the cylinder with the red line implying the plane along which I'd like to cut the cylinder.

[image: cylinder]

The second plot shows the corner coordinates after using `cutMeshPlane` to separate the cylinder along the z-axis. As desired, only the upper half remains.

[image: points]

However, I cannot plot a new 3d mesh representing half the cylinder. I believe that the vertex indices from `cylinder$ib` were not updated in `upperHalf$ib` and that's why. However, I cannot figure out how to solve this problem or create a new 3d mesh with the remaining coordinates. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Morpho::cutMeshPlane` function requires a mesh made of triangles, but yours is made up of quadrilaterals.  The simplest fix is to use `rgl::clipMesh3d` instead:

```
upperHalfrgl <- clipMesh3d(cylinder, "z", -200)
plot3d(upperHalfrgl, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab ="")
```

[image]

You could also convert your mesh to triangles using the internal `rgl` function `rgl:::as.tmesh3d`, but it's risky to use internal functions.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I just updated `cutMeshPlane` to also work with quad meshes. I tested with your example (see below)

you can install it using `devtools::install_github("zarquon42b/Morpho")`

[image]